# Form DataBase Design

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I'll try to explain my problem and let´s see if I get some help.

I`m trying to design a DB. This data base will contain users and forms but my problem is how to design it to save forms.

The forms will be created by the administrator when he needs them, so in the DB I have a table to save the form name. Another table with all the possible fields for all the forms and another table where form-names and fields will be save so I can see all the field that a determinated form has.

An example: In FormName table I have 3 form names: Personal Info, Computer Knowledgement and hobbies. And in Fields table I have, for example, Name, Address, Phone, Operating Systems, Programming, Bike ridding, playing pc games.

I decide to create a form with name number 1 (Personal info) and fields number 1,2,3 (Name, Address, Phone). This information is recorded in another table called full-form where it´s saved form name id and field id. This is pretty clear for me (perhaps I´wrong).

The tricky part comes now. Some user decide to fill the personal info form so the name of the form and each field will has to displayed. When the user fill the form it has to be saved some way so the administrator can see the name of the form, each field that that form has, who filled the form and the information written in each field.  And all this should be displayed not only in the DB but in some different way like a table, for example.

By the way... I´m using cakephp and mysql.

Thanks in advance,

Abraham

Comment: Sorry, hope now it´s more readable.

Comment: Take a look at the EAV design pattern.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Don't use EAV design unless you really really have well designed task. If you are looking to upgrade your code later with different features like sort or search, EAV is a poor choice. It could look easy to use at that point, but once you got things complicated you will have to implement a whole DB engine yourself. 
With one word: EAV = EVIL

Comment: One table per form is what I will do. There are not so much form to create.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, setup looks like this. As you said, we have 3 tables:

'formname' = id, name (for form names)
'formfields' = id, fieldname, attributes (for form names, added attributes in case you need them)
'forms' = id, formname_id, formfields_id, formfields_order (ready forms and possibility to order field in form)

And also you should create additional table where to store submitted values
'forms_values' = id, forms_id, value (in this case one row for each field)

If you want to relate those values to specific user, one more table should be created
'users_forms' = forms_values_id, user_id

Of course there should be users table as well.

My suggestion is to drop table 'formnames' and put form name in 'forms' table.
Then table 'forms' will contain
id, form_name, formfields_id, formfields_order

Hope this answer will put you forward :)